# Python module dependencies. How to get full list?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install pyinstaller on the machine that has no access to the web. I get an error:

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
```

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`

```
   command: 'c:\api\python38\python.exe' 'c:\api\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z666qxbs\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools
       cwd: None
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Collecting wheel
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000456B700>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000456BBE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000456BDF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000452E9D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000000452E7C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/wheel/
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\api\python38\python.exe' 'c:\api\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-z666qxbs\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools Check the logs for full command output
```

Can't find dependencies list for pyinstaller. What do i need to install first?
P.S. "wheel" module is installed.

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller requires two Python modules in a Windows system. It requires either the PyWin32 or pypiwin32 Python extension for Windows.
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requirements.html

Comment: both modules is installed: pywin32(301), pypiwin32(223) and also installed pefile(2021.5.24). Same error